# Zend framework 2 translations

Tags: zend-framework2, translation

hy,

Im trying to set translations in my zf2 app.

I added those to my module.config.php

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'abstract_factories' => array(
        'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
        'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
    ),
    'aliases' => array(
        'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
    ),
),
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'phparray',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.php',
            'text_domain' => __NAMESPACE__,
        ),
    ),
),
```

then in my Module.php

```
$translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
        $translator
            ->setLocale(\Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']))
            ->setFallbackLocale('en_US');
```

And I added under directory Admin/language file en_US.php

```
<?php
 return array(
   'Welcome' => array(
   'ASDSASD'
    ),    
)
```

And it doesn't work, any suggestions ...

Comment: Try this - http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/zend-framework-2-zendi18ntranslatortranslator-translate-your-web/